# queryParams add undefined in url?

Tags: angular

```
  <a class="choose_offer" [routerLink]="['/vpn/evidencija', children.key, query.SPECIFICATION_ID]" [queryParams]="{procesId:children.processId ? children.processId : procesId,
                P_SA_ID: P_SA_ID ? P_SA_ID : '' ,
                P_ES_ID: P_ES_ID ? P_ES_ID : '' ,
                P_BA_ID:P_BA_ID  ? P_BA_ID : '',
                P_CA_ID:P_CA_ID ? P_CA_ID : '' ,
                P_BAGG_ID:P_BAGG_ID ? P_BAGG_ID : '' ,
                P_SAGG_ID :P_SAGG_ID }" queryParamsHandling="merge">ODABERI</a>
```

I have this link and what i want is to remove from queryParams if its undefined. Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use below like codes

```
X: x === undefined || x === null ? '' : x,
Y: y === undefined || y === null ? '' : y, ...
```

Comment: it add empty value in url x= y=

Comment: i want to not display at all that params

Comment: You can define all these parameters youu need in typescript part (.ts)

Comment: Please specify and give some example. If you do not enter query parameters you can use another way instead of using queryParams